# Is it possible to connect to a mail server without hard coding the port using JavaMail api's, basically the code should be independent of ports. ?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am working on an application where the app should able to read/fetch the emails from a smtp server. The problem is the ports may differ in different environment. Is there any way to connect to smtp/pop (microsoft exchage) server without knowing the port. Any information might be helpful because of I am new to this javamail api's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are standard ports for these services, which JavaMail uses by default.  It's relatively rare that one of these services will use a non-standard port.  But you do need to know whether the service requires SSL or not, and there are two standard ports used for SMTP.  You could easily write code that tries all the common ports and you would probably cover 99.99% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be possible. Each port serves a different purpose.

What you can do is read your port number from an external property file, so that your code becomes environment independent, and then you just have to change the value in your property file which placed outside your deployed war/jar

This way, your port no value could be environment specific without having to change your code.